# How to configure multiple Material UI badges for the same content

Tags: material-ui

I have a design requirement to add multiple badges to a single piece of content. It doesn't seem to be a support use case in the docs. Has anyone implemented something like this? How should I approach this?

Comment: Did you find the answer?
I would like to show 3 badges one after another on the right corner for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily create a second badge the same way you would for the first badge.
Below is an example where the given content has two badges in different locations.

```
<materialDesign:Badged x:Name="ErrorBadge" BadgePlacementMode="TopRight">
   <materialDesign:Badged x:Name="WarningBadge" BadgePlacementMode="Right">
      // Content
   </materialDesign:Badged>
</materialDesign:Badged>
```

Comment: What syntax / language is this?

Comment: @FooBar xaml / WPF